# Poker hand analyze and clean code

Tags: java, coding-style, poker

I have a question more about style rather than implementation. I'm working on poker application. It has a class storing all required data, like five cards. There is also second structure, which models the FigureAnalyzer - piece of code to determine, whever the hand contains flush, two pairs or full. In general, everything is working fine. But it's more ugly then my ex-girlfriend.

This is a sample, which determine hand combination:

```
@Override
public int getFigureStrength(IHand hand) {
/*
 * analyze all possible pairs, triples, etc.
 */
    MultipleCardAnalyzer.anayzeMultipleCards(hand, figureList);
    hand.setFigureAnalyzer(this);

    if (isPoker()) {
        if (isRoyalPoker())
            return 10;
        return 9;
    }

    else if (isFourOfAKind())
        return 8;

    else if (isFull())
        return 7;

    else if (isFlush())
        return 6;

    else if (isStraight())
        return 5;

    else if (areThreeOfAKind())
        return 4;

    else if (areTwoPairs())
        return 3;

    else if (isPair())
        return 2;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Numbers are useful when it comes to comparing two hands. But... it's just awful. Can any one point me or just suggest, how can I make it more pretty?

Comment: if you don't get feedback here, then try http://codereview.stackexchange.com -- your question fits their site perfectly

Comment: [Enumerations?](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Enumeration+java)

Comment: Ok, enums makes one thing, but all those if/elses... Any idea how to make it more readible?

Comment: Frankly, the rules of poker are a mess of special cases, so if code implementing them is a mess of special cases, that's not necessarily a bad thing. The only thing above I might reasonably object to is the name of the function isPoker(), which apparently ought to be isStraightFlush(). I'm curious, is the name of the game the same as the name of the straight flush in Polish? It's common for a game to be named after its "goal", but in Spanish and other languages it's named after the four-of-a-kind hand ("el Pokar"), because poker didn't have straights and flushes until after the Civil War.

Comment: I was just about to write a funny thing, that I was aware of wrong name for Straight Flush, but Poker is the name for this in polish, so it just feels right for me ;) So you got me. But in polish everything is hard and strange.

Comment: That makes sense. The game probably didn't make it to Poland until after the Civil War, by which time it had straights and flushes. Interesting historical tidbit.

Answer (score 2):

Define constants w/ meaningful names for these values; an `enum` might be useful here.